# Probability Theory Of Additive Property of Variance

Tags: probability-theory

Proving $Var(X\pm c)$ $=$ $Var(X$

Let $t$ $=$ $E(X)$

Then we know $E(X\pm c$) $=$ $t\pm c$

So $Var(X\pm c)$ $=$ $E[((X\pm c) - (t\pm c))^2$

I am unsure on where to go from here, not sure if I expand $(t\pm c))^2$ or if I'm taking a wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify the term inside the square.
\begin{align}
Var(X+c) &= E([X+c-(t+c)]^2 ) \\
&= E((X-t)^2)\\
&= Var(X)
\end{align}

Comment: Does this mean this works for $Var(X-c)$ as well?

Comment: Yes, repeat the procedure to verify it.

Comment: Wow, it is literally simple algebra, thank you Siong.

Comment: Alternatively, we have proven that $Var(X+d) = Var(X)$, now let $d=-c$. Also, physically it means if you shift a pmf/ pdf by a constant, the variation of distance to the mean doesn't change.